# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Int when using akka 2.5.6 with sbt version 1.0.2

Tags: sbt, typesafe-config

I am trying to use akka -remoting version 2.5.4 with latest sbt 1.0.2

When I use sbt version 0.13.15 or 0.13.16 it is working very well.

But when I'm using sbt verion 1.0.2 as [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/AkkaRemotingExamples/blob/master/project/build.properties#L2), I'm getting below error.

The Below exception is runtime exception.

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Int
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Int
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:74)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]     at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.$anonfun$getClassFor$1(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:21)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]     at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:20)
[error]     at akka.serialization.Serialization.$anonfun$bindings$3(Serialization.scala:313)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$map$2(TraversableLike.scala:739)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:462)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:738)
[error]     at akka.serialization.Serialization.<init>(Serialization.scala:311)
[error]     at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:15)
[error]     at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:880)
[error]     at akka.actor.ExtensionId.apply(Extension.scala:77)
[error]     at akka.actor.ExtensionId.apply$(Extension.scala:77)
[error]     at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.apply(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
[error]     at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:203)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:796)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:793)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:793)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:809)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:244)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:287)
[error]     at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:262)
[error]     at module09.remoteB.RemoteBStartup$.main(RemoteBStartup.scala:8)
[error]     at module09.remoteB.RemoteBStartup.main(RemoteBStartup.scala)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error]     at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:83)
[error]     at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:61)
[error]     at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]     at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The github location is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/AkkaRemotingExamples)

To me, this looks like the error is because of `ConfigFactory.load` as in [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/AkkaRemotingExamples/blob/master/src/main/scala/module09/remoteB/RemoteBStartup.scala#L8) is having some issues due to sbt latest version.

Comment: same problem, downgraded to 0.13.16 and it works now

Comment: upgrading to 1.1.0 should also do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in sbt, so I [filed it as such](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3736) and it has been fixed in sbt version 1.1.0.

(If this would have turned out out to be hard to resolve, we might have considered to [implement a workaround in Akka](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/24098), but this turned out not to be needed)

Comment: hey Arnaut, what is the solution for this? It seems there is not much details out there in github issues.

Comment: I think this needs to be fixed in sbt (or in Akka if it turns out it does not make sense to fix it in sbt for some reason after all) - for now the easiest way out might be to stay at sbt 0.13.16

Comment: (the bug has since been fixed, updating my answer accordingly)

Comment: Thanks @ArnoutEngelen! Would have been digging around for a while if not for your hint here!

Answer (score 2):

Adding `fork in run := true` (which will fork the JVM to run the task) appears to solve the problem with sbt.

This workaround is pointed out as a response on [the issue opened by @Arnout](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3736#issuecomment-349993007)