# SBT 1.x fails to resolve parent pom

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt1.0

My SBT `1.1.0` setup fails to resolve parent dependency as a POM file.

We have several libraries published in a local Sonatype repository. All of them depend on 1 maven project with `<packaging>pom</packaging>` property set. So there is no `JAR` file in the repo, only declarative `POM` file for this parent project and this `POM` is available and accessible.

SBT `0.13.17` resolves this chain successfully and downloads libraries plus this parent `POM`.

But SBT `1.x` fails with error:

`unresolved dependency: ... unable to get resource for  commons-dependencies-parent-2.165.jar`

It's trying to download `JAR` instead of `POM` file.

I was trying to specify this parent dependency explicitly with

`"com.zeptolab.commons" % "commons-dependencies-parent" % "2.165"`

But the bug persists.

Any ideas or workarounds? Have already switched all projects to SBT `1.1.0` except this one due to this problem.

UPD. Custom resolver is properly set up and working with sbt 0.13.17

UPD2 Made an issue https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3953

Comment: what is the exact version of sbt you are using?

Comment: With any 1.x version. Now it’s 1.1.0

Comment: looks like the artifcat for `com.zeptolab.commons` is not standard maven. You need to include the `resolvers += ` which has the dependency you are adding in your project.

Comment: I’ve written that sbt 0.13.17 works and custom resolvers with my local repo are properly set up with resolvers +=

Comment: okay looks like there is bug in SBT. I had some similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46982706/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-scala-int-when-using-akka-2-5-6-with-sbt-versi which was working in 0.13.16 but not in 1.0.x. So make small project that replicates your issue and file a bug in SBT https://github.com/sbt/sbt.

Comment: It's definitely not the same issue. In my case I don't have exceptions. SBT just trying to download JAR file instead of POM file from local repo.

Comment: I'm not saying it is same issue. It is similar issue(i.e., something works in previous version but not in latest version). Even for my issue I thought the same, but the guy from Lightbend convinced me that it is SBT issue. you can go through the conversations in the link I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround for this issue. Looks like there is a bug in new http client. 
So setting `updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withGigahorse(false)` helps.